# getting same tfidf values for different words

Tags: python-3.x, sentiment-analysis, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

So i am doing a project regarding twitter sentiment analysis, wherein i happen to need to use TFIDF on the collected tweets.
So i converted the list of tweets into a single string and fed that to the object, the problem is that i am getting identical values for most of the words with some different values but they are also very frequent. Why is this happening ? Is it cause i am using a single string as input?

here is the code https://trinket.io/python/9c2daed912

[Here is the screenshot, as you can see many have same TFIDF values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4BzZ.jpg)

Comment: Please consider pasting your code/error log directly; see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

The frequency can be the same number for different words based on how many times it occurs. My code for project gutenberg results in the following.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tfvect = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
### The corpus is from Project Gutenberg after all the text cleanup.
karlmarx_freq = tfvect.fit_transform(gutenberg_KarlMarx_Corpus)

tftermFreq = pd.DataFrame(karlmarx_freq.toarray(),columns=tfvect.get_feature_names())
tfsumdf = tftermFreq.sum(axis=0)
pd.DataFrame({'Vocab': tfsumdf.index, 'Frequency': tfsumdf.values}).sort_values(by='Frequency', ascending=False)
```

The results are:

1412    production  0.177513

345 conditions  0.174032

1151    modern  0.142706

1704    social  0.128784

1000    labour  0.128784

641 existence   0.111381

1705    socialism   0.104419

1117    means   0.100939

923 industry    0.100939

For details regarding, how this calculation is made, please refer to [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#tfidf-term-weighting) documentation.

Tf-Idf = Term frequency * Inverse Document frequency